# Multiple animation on button, only the last one shows

Tags: android

I have one animation that I want to implement on 3 different buttons, but for some reason when I press them, only the last button pressed starts the animation, the animation on the other two buttons stops functioning. I saw one answer on stackoverflow but I did not understand it. Also I've noticed that if I copy the animation code twice and name it animation2 and animation 3, and add that to the buttons then it works, but I'm assuming that's very memory inefficient. Heres my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    final Button a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    final Button a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a3);


    final AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a2), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a4), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a5), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a6), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a7), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a8), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a9), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a10), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a11), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a12), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a13), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a14), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a15), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a16), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a17), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a18), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a19), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a20), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a21), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a22), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a23), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a24), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a25), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a26), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a27), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a28), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a29), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a30), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a31), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a32), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a33), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a34), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a35), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a36), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a37), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a38), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a39), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a40), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a41), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a42), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a43), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a44), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a45), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a46), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a47), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a48), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a49), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a50), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a51), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a52), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a53), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a54), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a55), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a56), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a57), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a58), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a59), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a60), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a61), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a62), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a63), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a64), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a65), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a66), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a67), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a68), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a69), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a70), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a71), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a72), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a73), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a74), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a75), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a76), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a77), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a78), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a79), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a80), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a81), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a82), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a83), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a84), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a85), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a86), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a87), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a88), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a89), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a90), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a91), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a92), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a93), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a94), 20);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a95), 20);

    animation.setOneShot(false);




    a1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    a1.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

                    animation.start();



                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    animation.stop();

                    //a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.index1);




                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    a2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    a2.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

                    animation.start();



                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    animation.stop();

                    //a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.index1);




                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    a3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    a3.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

                    animation.start();



                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    animation.stop();

                    //a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.index1);




                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Define Three AnimationDrawable  object for each button.

Comment: ya that Three AnimationDrawable will be a way

Comment: yes, I found that I could do that but isn't that really inefficient? what if I had not 3 but 30buttons, would it not slow down the phone considerably? isn't there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you define your animation in as XML in a res/drawable/ directory. That way you can re-use the definition in separate AnimationDrawables.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured it out! Here's the xml code that you need to put in the drawable folder code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<animation-list   android:id="@+id/custom_button" android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="20" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a2" android:duration="20" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a3" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a4" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a5" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a6" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a7" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a8" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a9" android:duration="20" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a10" android:duration="20" />
</animation-list>
```

and here is the rest

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    final Button a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    final Button a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a3);




    a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
    a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
    a3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);


    final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) a1.getBackground();
    final AnimationDrawable anim2 = (AnimationDrawable) a2.getBackground();
    final AnimationDrawable anim3 = (AnimationDrawable) a3.getBackground();







    a1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:



                    anim.start();



                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    anim.stop();





                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    a2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    anim2.start();



                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    anim2.stop();



                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    a3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    anim3.start();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                    anim3.stop();


                    // End
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });



}
```

}